# Class gets no data from xhmtl input field

Tags: maven, jsf, intellij-idea, jsf-2

I have a JavaEE 7 application and want to get input over an xhtml page. Unfortunately only the by the POJO generated ID is saved. I use JSF.

```
<h:form>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Titel:</label>
  <h:inputText value="#{currentBook.title}" styleClass="form-control"/>
 </div>
</h:form>
```

The Class CurrentBook is part of the model and contains all attributes, that the POJO Class has, getter and setter and a with @PostConstruct annotated initialize method, which sets default values. CurrentBook is annotated with @Named for JSF and @RequestScoped.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mms.book-store</groupId>
    <artifactId>book-store</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <finalName>com.mms.book-store</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I suspect, that I am missing some dependencies or have some double (I heard CDI and JSF are in Java EE already). JSF is enabled in this IntelliJ project.

Thanks for reading :)

Edit: After marking all dependencies as povided, I still have the Problem, that my input isn't set.

```
10:47:29,353 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) Hibernate: insert into books (author, isbn, title, year) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
10:47:29,393 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) Book ID is 1
```

Comment: What application server are you using?

Comment: It's a Wildfly 11.

Comment: All your dependencies should be of scope "provided" because they are already contained in Wildfly. If you don't do so your app will not work as expected.

Comment: Really all of them? Does provided mean I can leave them out?

Comment: Provided means that you can use this dependencies in your code but they will not be included in the lib folder of your WAR file because they are PROVIDED by Wildfly

Comment: BalusC made a link to a similar question and if you read it you will see "Always mark server-provided libraries as provided"

Comment: I already corrected this. Problem still exists, I edited the question.

Comment: You should start a new question because this one is closed thru marking as duplicate

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.